# C++ immutable struct

Tags: c++, functional-programming, immutability

I would like to be able to implement immutable data in C++. In short, given a C++ object in which I would like to modify a member variable, instead of modifying that member in place I would like to get a new copy the object with the member being modified.

To address this, I wrote a small template class to represent the immutable field:

```
template <typename ParentStruct, typename T>
class ImmutableField {
public:

  ParentStruct set(const T& newNalue) const {
    ParentStruct dst = *(getParentPointer());
    reinterpret_cast<ImmutableField<ParentStruct, T>*>((
        reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&dst) + _offsetInParent))->_value = newNalue;
    return dst;
  }

  const T& get() const {
    return _value;
  }

private:
  friend ParentStruct;

  ImmutableField(const ParentStruct* parent, const T& init = T()) : 
    _offsetInParent(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(this) - reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(parent)),
    _value(init) {}

  const ParentStruct* getParentPointer() const {
    return reinterpret_cast<const ParentStruct*>(
      reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(this) - _offsetInParent);
  }

  T _value;
  int64_t _offsetInParent = 0;
};
```

As template parameter, it takes the type of the class it would belong to, and the type of the value that it stores. It has two public methods, `get` and `set`. Note that `set` is `const` and returns a `ParentStruct` representing the updated version of ParentStruct.

Now I can, for instance, use it to implement a complex number like this:

```
double sqr(double x) {return x*x;}

struct ComplexNumber {
  ComplexNumber() : real(this), imag(this) {}

  ImmutableField<ComplexNumber, double> real;
  ImmutableField<ComplexNumber, double> imag;

  double abs() const {
    return sqrt(sqr(real.get()) + sqr(imag.get()));
  }
};
```

And some basic testing suggests that it works:

```
#define CHECK(X) if (!(X)) {std::cerr << "Check " #X " failed." << std::endl; abort();}

int main() {

  ComplexNumber x = ComplexNumber().real.set(3.0).imag.set(4.0);
  CHECK(x.abs() == 5.0);

  std::cout << "So far, so good!" << std::endl;

  ComplexNumber y = x.real.set(12).imag.set(5);

  CHECK(y.abs() == 13.0);

  std::cout << "It still works!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**My question is**: Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do and is there a library for doing this in a cleaner way? The `ImmutableField` class seems extremely hacky with lots of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Why do you need the `real.set(3.0)` syntax? A `using ComplexNumber = const std::complex<double>;` is likely better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the goal of using immutable types is usually laudable, your specific implementation is excessively clever, involves loads of UB, and will fail for any ParentStruct that is not *trivially copyable*. Furthermore, your field instances are bound to a specific instance. As these fields must not be copied around, you should at least delete copy constructors and assignment operators. Also note that your fields each have a comparatively huge `int64_t` sized overhead – they are not a zero-cost abstraction! (Also, you should have probably used `ptrdiff_t` types rather than explicit integer types.)

Part of your conceptual problem is that C++ is a value-oriented language, not a reference-oriented language like Java. In C++, a variable *is* the object. A variable cannot be re-assigned to a different object, but we can overwrite the contents of the object with a new value. This has direct impact on how we think about immutability.
In particular, having mutable values is not immediately problematic. Where we want to disallow changes to a value through a specific reference (such as a variable name), we can mark that reference `const`.

C++ already has an acceptable way to create a new object with only one field changed: make a copy, then change that field.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct ComplexNumber {
  ComplexNumber() : real(), imag() {}
  ComplexNumber(double real, double imag) : real(real), imag(imag) {}

  double real;
  double imag;

  double abs() const {
    return std::sqrt(real*real + imag*imag);
  }
};

#define CHECK(X) if (!(X)) {std::cerr << "Check " #X << " failed." << std::endl; abort();}

int main() {
  const ComplexNumber x = ComplexNumber(3.0, 4.0);
  CHECK(x.abs() == 5.0);

  std::cout << "So far, so good!" << std::endl;

  ComplexNumber y = x;
  y.real = 12;
  y.imag = 5;

  CHECK(y.abs() == 13.0);

  std::cout << "It still works!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If `y` is supposed to be `const`, then we can use an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
const ComplexNumber y = [&]() {
  ComplexNumber y = x;
  y.real = 12;
  y.imag = 5;
  return y;
}();
```

(which, thanks to copy elision, does not require a copy of inner-`y` to the outer variable.)

This pattern is also nicely generalizable so that you could write a macro to define setter-methods:

```
#define SETTER(type, name) \
  auto with_##name(type value) const { \
    auto copy = *this; \
    copy.name = value; \
    return copy; \
  }
```

Then: `const ComplexNumber y = x.with_real(12).with_imag(5)` at the cost of an extra copy.

Comment: Using those type-transformations from `<type_traits>` is severe overkill for the macro. The verbosity obscures the purpose. Otherwise nice one.

Comment: @Deduplicator good point, fixed. That overly general approach also led to a silly `double const&` type. I've changed the macro signature to be invoked as `SETTER(double, real)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this answer points out issues about my proposed approach but *does not give any details*. **First**, regarding *"involves loads of UB"*, could you give a small example of such UB, preferably a piece of code? **Second**, regarding *"will fail for any ParentStruct that is not trivially copyable"*, (i) how will it fail and (ii) can you give an example of how it would fails if, say, I would add an "std::vector<std::string> tags" member to the ComplexNumber? Because "std::vector<std::string>" is arguably not trivially copyable.

Comment: Another point: What do you mean by "As these fields must not be copied around"? I don't see any problem with the *copying itself*, as the ImmutableField class only contains T and int64_t. The problem I see is if someone makes a copy of the field to a local variable and then call the "set" method on that local variable, since that would mean the getParentPointer() returns a pointer to something that is not of ParentStruct.

Comment: @Rulle This is not Stack Overflow, I will not flip through the C++ standard to figure out why exactly your reinterpret-casts are UB (probably in the fine-print of \[basic.stc.dynamic.safety]). If the fields are copied or moved, dereferencing the parent pointer may segfault because `this` is different. If the parent is not trivially copyable then there might be constructors that perform validation. By directly setting the field you are bypassing any encapsulation, and could bring the parent object copy into an invalid state. Arguably the fault of the parent, though, for exposing the field.

Comment: Btw. this expression is UB because of how pointer subtraction is defined: `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(this) - reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(parent)` – “if P and Q point to, respectively, elements x[i] and x[j] of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i−j. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.” (\[expr.add]). Here, the pointers do not point to elements of the _same_ array object.

Comment: @amon This is a good point, regarding pointer arithmetics. I did not know that they had to belong to the *same* array.

Comment: I think the conclusion is that the my approach to immutability has too many issues, notably regarding UB (e.g. pointer differences being UB) as pointed out in the comment, so I will accept this answer. Thank you!